# Array Destructuring + spread syntax with specific field only?

Tags: javascript, arrays, destructuring, spread-syntax

```
let arr = [{name: 'john', age:17}, {name: 'Doe', age: 21}];

//let dropDownHumanOptions = ['All', ...arr.name, 'Cancel']
//let dropDownHumanOptions = ['All', ...{arr.name}, 'Cancel']

//Expected: let dropDownHumanOptions = ['All', 'john', 'Doe', 'Cancel']
```

I'm wondering if there is any similar syntax where we can just extracting one of the field and combine in the middle of another array by using spread syntax?

Comment: You can only destructure to a standalone variable. For what you're looking for, you need to `.map`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to spread the mapped names.

```js
var array = [{name: 'john', age:17}, {name: 'Doe', age: 21}],
    dropDownHumanOptions = ['All', ...array.map(({ name }) => name), 'Cancel'];

console.log(dropDownHumanOptions);
```